# How to use Varnish HTTP-Cache in Laradock?

Tags: laravel, varnish, laradock

Laradock has support in Varnish HTTP-Cache but I can't find any sample implementation.

Does anyone here have tried using varnish in laradock? Help please.

Comment: It's frustrating. https://www.google.com/search?q=varnish+site%3Alaradock.io seems to imply that Laradock supports Varnish, and so does https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/v7.2.0/env-example#L284, but I can't find any instructions. Did you, John? Thanks.

Comment: could you give an example how upstream for varnish proxy is defined please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varnish Laradock is using proxy

You can configure your .env variables for varnish.

and run `docker-compose up proxy.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/v7.2.0/docker-compose.yml#L602 (and https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/925#issuecomment-300773388)